High Quality Vegan Blackboard Chalk
I recently discovered that Hagoromo chalk is made using crushed oyster shells (mentioned about four minutes into this video). I use a blackboard both to teach a class, as well as for working on my own mathematical research, so I do not want to switch back to using cheap chalk like Crayola.
Does anyone know of any chalk that is of roughly similar quality to Hagoromo, but is vegan?
